# iOS9 App moves to root view controller while coming back from background

Tags: ios, ios9

My application is having 2 views. Login view and Home view. On successful authentication user will be navigated to Home view.

Issue I am facing here is that , in iOS9 devices when the application is in background for long time it will be going to login view (Which is the root view controller).Is this expected behaviour in iOS 9? Because I am not getting this behaviour on older OS versions.

Few more clarifications:
App is a VoIP application, So background running mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe apple reduced the time to kill an application running in background in ios9. Better implement verify your authentication in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` using CoreData or NSUserDefaults

Answer (score -1):

just do it in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled =YES;